# intelliJ doesn't accept java 9 JDK

Tags: java, openjdk, intellij

I'm trying to use java 9 in intelliJ while using Ubuntu 16.4 with a KDE desktop.
I find myself unable to select my JDK file in the editor. I have java 8 and 9 installed, and currently java 9 is set to run with the java command. As a sidenote: I am able to use jshell.

`$ java -version` returns:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

and this is my `$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Feb 25  2016 default-java -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Okt 28 00:51 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-8-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Apr 14  2016 java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-9-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 11 18:03 java-8-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 11 18:04 java-9-openjdk-amd64
```

[Screenshot of intelliJ selection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zscE.png)
If i press OK while java-1.8.0 is selected, it accepts it as the JDK. If, however, i select the folder below it, containing java-1.9.0, it tells me "The selceted directory is not a valid home for JDK" [As is shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENqWx.png)
It makes no difference if i use the java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64 link or the java-9-openjdk-amd64 directory.

If it is of any significance: I installed openjdk with the apt command.

#### Edit:

- I'm using intelliJ IDEA Version 2017.2.5
- I installed the openJDK 9 : `sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk` and then had an error in dpkg which was resolved by using `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install openjdk-9-jdk`

Comment: Do you have last version of IntelliJ? You need as I know 2017.2 version

Comment: Java 9 is fully supported in all of the 2017 releases

Comment: Which IntelliJ version are you running and how did you install OpenJDK 9?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue with v2017.3 after following the same installation steps as you did.

Comment: I concur with OP.  Its not an issue of Java 9 being supported or not as @ThilankaDeshan-minion91 would imply .. however its an issue with how Intelli-J (same version as OP) is failing to recognize the Open-JDK home dir. I don't really need Java 9 so I installed 8 and it worked. Again .. this is a problem with Intelli-J failing to recognize the OpenJDK home folder

Comment: This I think is a bug that need attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem but I got around it. Try this.

1. Download Java JDK 9 [zip](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/9) or [tar.gz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) (I used this so everything I say afterwards will reflect this).
2. Once downloaded, extract the tar.gz file in your location of choice (please take note of the location, you will come back to it later).
3. Open IntelliJ and go to *Project Structure* under *Files*. Under *Project SDK*, navigate to the location in 2. above and select it.

**Alternatively**, go to *Files* > *Project* *Structure* > *Platform* *Settings*. Once again, add the location in 2. above (green plus sign) if you do not see it in the pane.

I hope this will help you and you will enjoy Java 9 as well as jShell.

Comment: I suggest extracting the .tar.gz file in step 2. to a root owned directory like `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: First of all, thanks! In step 2, I extracted the tar.gz file to /usr/local/bin/java (created the folder for that purpose) and I was wondering is that is a 'good' way of doing it, or if I should have placed it in /usr/local/bin? I tried to avoid having a bulky bin folder, since I put custom commands in there as well.

Comment: Not thought of that but it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I found it; it is probably not specific for Ubuntu, but it has to do with a jar (lib/jrt-fs.jar) that wasn't compiled correctly in openjdk-9..

the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296429/properly-set-up-java-9-as-sdk-in-intellij-idea-on-linux-due-to-new-folder-struct/47850159#47850159

I quote: *A temporary workaround may be replacing **/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/jrt-fs.jar** with the one from Oracle JDK*.

After I replaced the jar I could add the SDK to IntelliJ without any problem.